# Binding static class to ListBox and TextBlock

Tags: wpf, binding, static

```
User Class
- Name
- Picture

Friend Class
- Profile Of Type User
- Age

MyProfile STATIC Class
- STATIC Profile Of Type User
- STATIC Friends Collection Of Type Friend
```

-- EDIT --

How to bind to the following :
- MyProfile.Friends To List Box which Contains Text blocks to have Friends Names
- MyProfile.Profile.Name To Textblock

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you define a namespace in your xaml to your C# namespace. I've named it local.

MyProfile.Friends To List Box which Contains Text blocks to have Friends Names

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static local:MyProfile.Friends}">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Profile.Name}" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

MyProfile.Profile.Name To Textblock

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Static local:MyProfile.Profile.Name}" />
```

Comment: NOT working as i don't have AnyOne value ; so i do a listview binding with Myprofile.Friends , how to bind Names to textblocks inside listview

Comment: You did have AnyOne value a few moments ago before you edited the question.

Comment: No No you didn't understand me ,, i wrote AnyOne as i didn't know it

Comment: Make sure that classes implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface. this should be enough for Profile Class. For Friends i think you should use ObservableCollection Class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx. I have used it sucessfully for a similar job. I am not also sure about these fields being static. Will they let you implement the interfaces withe the static keyword?