# WPF binding a class to listbox

Tags: wpf, expression-blend

I have used exprssion blend4 edit itemcontainerstyle and increased 3 textblocks in item. NOW,  i want to bind the 3 textblocks to a class. The class has 3 different properties. For example,i has a student class,student has name ,age,and major.I want to bind whole school students to listbox and each textblocks display specific information.

Comment: try this link:

[binding class to list box and text block][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087219/binding-static-class-to-listbox-and-textblock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read at least the MSDN [Data Binding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx). It provides the necessary basic knowledge about data binding in WPF.